# What's the best reference for Abelian varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

I am curious about learning about Abelian varieties, specifically how they are in some ways generalizations of elliptic curves.

I know of the two sources: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf and *Abelian varieties* by Serge Lang.

Are there others? Which is the best for the viewpoint expressed above?

Comment: There's also Mumford.

Comment: This book project http://van-der-geer.nl/~gerard/AV.pdf by Edixhoven, van der Geer and Moonen looks promising.

Comment: Mumford's Tata Lectures, especially volumes 1 and 3 were excellent references. Mumford also had a little red book, with alot of characteristic p, which i never used. But the Tata lectures had the most detail concerning the different linear algebraic descriptions of "abelian variety". I studied them as symplectic lattices, flat 2g-dimensional real tori with symplectic and complex structures parameterized by Riemann Conditions and Siegel Upper Half space.

Comment: If you're interested in an informal and arithmetically oriented introduction, I can recommend Davide Lombardo's notes: https://people.dm.unipi.it/lombardo/Teaching/VarietaAbeliane1718/Notes.pdf

Comment: Mumford is the classic, of course. For a first introduction, [Bhatt's notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/abelian_varieties.pdf) are also pretty good; they use a more up to date language.